# Convert $\frac1b\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(b e^a)^n}{n!}B_{n-1}(an)$ to integral using $B_n(x)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint\frac{e^{x(e^t-1)}}{t^{n+1}}dt$

Tags: polynomials, contour-integration, transcendental-equations, fubini-tonelli-theorems, lagrange-inversion

$\def\B{\operatorname B}$
In

> [How to solve $x^{y^z}=z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4652764/how-to-solve-xyz-z/4653705#4653705)

A solution uses [Bell polynomials $\B_n(x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials)

$$e^{ae^{bz}}=z=1+\frac1b\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(ae^b)^n}{nn!}\B_n(b n)=\frac1b\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(b e^a)^n}{n!}\B_{n-1}(an)\tag1$$

A [contour integral representation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials#Properties) is:

> $$\B_n(x)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint\frac{e^{x(e^t-1)}}{t^{n+1}}dt\tag2$$

interchanging sum and integral gives:
$$e^{ae^{bz}}=z\mathop=^?1+\frac i{2\pi b}\oint\ln\left(1-\frac{ae^{be^t}}t\right)dt\mathop=^?\frac i{2\pi b}\oint\ln\left(1-\frac{be^{ae^t}}t\right)dt$$

I have little experience with contour integration, but trying $a=b=-\frac12$ and $\oint\leftrightarrow\int_{\frac12-i\infty}^{\frac12+i\infty}$ [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Nintegrate%5B%28-0.397887+i%29+log%281+%2B+%280.4+e%5E%28-0.4+e%5E%28i+t%2B1%2F2%29%29%29%2F%28i+t%2B1%2F2%29%29%2C%7Bt%2C-infty%2Cinfty%7D%5D) a different result than [the sum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=+sum%5B%28b+e%5Ea%29%5En%2F%28b+n%21%29+BellB%28n-1%2Can%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C10%7D%5D%2Ca%3Db%3D-0.4%5D). Likely, the contour used is wrong or one cannot switch the sum and integral without converting to an ordinary integral.

How can $(2)$ be used in $(1)$ to find a similar contour integral solution to $e^{ae^{bz}}=z$?

Comment: The contour is indeed wrong: $\oint$ implies a closed path. This typically means integrating from $\tau=0\to1$ and that $C:z=w_0+Re^{2\pi i \tau}.$

Answer (score 1):

(WIP) Interchange the sum and the integral, and integrate on the path $z=r_0e^{2\pi i \tau}$ from $0$ to $1$. Take the limit as $r_0\to 0$ like so

$$b^{-1}\sum \frac{b^ne^{an}}{2\pi in}\oint \frac{e^{an(e^{t}-1)}}{t^n}dt\\=b^{-1}\oint \sum \frac{b^ne^{an}}{2\pi in} \frac{e^{an(e^{t}-1)}}{t^n}dt\\=\frac{b^{-1}}{2\pi i}\oint \sum \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{be^{ae^t}}{t}\right)^ndt\\ =-\frac{b^{-1}}{2\pi i}\oint \ln\left(1-\frac{be^{ae^t}}{t}\right)dt\\ = -b^{-1}\lim_{r_0\to0}\int_0^1r_0e^{2\pi i\tau}\ln\left(1-\frac{be^{ae^{r_0e^{2\pi i\tau}}}}{r_0e^{2\pi i\tau}}\right)d\tau$$ Now, I know what you're thinking, and I'm also very overwhelmed... however with a bit of faith, I think we can proceed with the limit using asymptotics and L'Hopital's rule.

---

However, if you want an inverse function for $e^{ae^{bz}}-z,$ you can use the Cauchy Integral Theorem to get

$$f^{-1}(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{f^{-1}\gamma} \frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)-w}dz$$

Comment: [Trying](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim%5Bh+e%5E%282+pi+i+catalan%29+ln%281-+baxter+e%5E%28glaisher+e%5E%28h+e%5E%282+pi+i+catalan%29%29%29%2F%28h+e%5E%282+pi+i+catalan%29%29%29%2Ch-%3E0%5D) various positive, negative, and complex $a,b$ makes the limit $0$, unless the limit and integral cannot be switched.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Normally I would want to be right about my choice of contour, but since the integral looks worse I'll say "*hopefully* I got the contour wrong".

Comment: Maybe you can try another contour?

Comment: @TymaGaidash I'll attempt. I don't think I deserve the 50+ you gave, (at least not yet), but I'll get back to you with something. Can you reference where you found the contour definition of the Bell functions?

Comment: It is in the [Bell polynomial representation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials#Properties) link of the question. It is under “basic properties” in the source

Answer (score 0):

Using @Gary’s Bell polynomial [integral representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4706744/905886), we get:

$$\frac1b\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(b e^a)^n}{n!}\text B_{n-1}(an)=\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{\left(ae^{e^{it}}-a-i t\right)n+it}(b e^a)^n}{2\pi b n}dt$$

with something similar for the second sum in the question. Now apply the series expansion of $\ln(x)$:

$$\bbox[2px,border: 2.5px ridge green]{e^{ae^{bx}}=x=-\frac1{2\pi b}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{it}\ln\left(1-be^{ae^{e^{it}}-it}\right)dt,1-\frac1{2\pi b}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\ln\left(1-ae^{be^{e^{it}}-it}\right)dt}$$

[shown](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=FIndRoot%5Be%5E%28-0.7+e%5E%280.3+x%29%29-x%2C%7Bx%2C0.4%7D%5D%2CNIntegrate%5B-%28e%5E%28i+t%29+log%281+-+%280.3%29+e%5E%28%28-0.7+%29e%5E%28e%5E%28i+t%29%29+-+i+t%29%29%29%2F%282+0.3+%CF%80%29%2C%7Bt%2C-%CF%80%2C%CF%80%7D%5D) [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=FindRoot%5Be%5E%28-0.7+e%5E%280.3+x%29%29-x%2C%7Bx%2C0.4%7D%5D%2C1%2BNIntegrate%5B-log%281+-+%28-0.7%29+e%5E%28%280.3%29+e%5E%28e%5E%28i+t%29%29+-+i+t%29%29%2F%282%280.3%29+%CF%80%29%2C%7Bt%2C-%CF%80%2C%CF%80%7D%5D). Software gives a [restriction](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B1%2Fb+%28a+e%5Eb%29%5En%2F%28n+n%21%29++n%21%2F%282+%CF%80%29+exp%28%28e%5Ee%5E%28i+t%29-1%29+b+n-+i+t+n%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2Cinfty%7D%5D) when summing over $n$, but it is not clear how to apply it to the integral representation. Taking $a=b$ gives another integral representation of the [Lambert W function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) solving $e^{ax}=x$. Additionally, one can remove the logarithm with integration by parts to get a slightly longer integral expression. It also may be interesting to take the real part of the integrand.